# Abrir input file con nombre de archivo predeterminado

Tags: vue.js

tengo un v-file-input en Vue, lo que quiero es que al darle clic y abra el dialogo para seleccionar el archivo este traiga un nombre por default, por ejemplo: namedefault (como en la imagen mas abajo).

mi codigo es este:

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" >
   <v-file-input ref="filexml" dense outlined required :label="t.uploadXML" accept=".xml" small-chips truncate-length="13" v-model="filexml" :rules="rules.filexml"></v-file-input>
   <v-spacer></v-spacer>
   <v-file-input ref="filepdf" dense outlined required :label="t.uploadPDF" accept=".pdf" show-size small-chips truncate-length="13" v-model="filepdf" :rules="rules.filepdf"></v-file-input>
</v-col>
```

lo que quiero es mostrar es esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues va a ser que no puedes. De la documentación: `You cannot set the value of a file picker from a script` que significa que no puedes establecer el valor (nombre del archivo) usando Javascript o cualquier otro método. Esto como parte de las medidas de seguridad propias del navegador. Referencia: [MDN `input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#notes). Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, entiendo que es un tema de seguridad solo quería saber si había alguna forma. gracias!!